# Java XPath with default Namespace issue

Tags: xpath

I am not able to ready node for expression

```
    <ns:Msg xmlns:ns="http://www.noventus.se/epix1" xmlns="http:www.defaultnamespace.com">
       <ns:Header>
          <SubsysId>1</SubsysId>
          <SubsysType>30003</SubsysType>
          <SendDateTime>2009-08-13T14:28:15</SendDateTime>
       </ns:Header>
    </ns:Msg>
```

I am having this kind of xml with contains two namespaces 1 is with ns and other one is default one.
I am trying to get value for SubsysId using org.dom4j.XPath and adding namespace with

```
    Map namespaces = new HashMap();
    namespaces.put("ns", "http://www.noventus.se/epix1");
    namespaces.put("main", "http:www.defaultnamespace.com");
```

Adding these namespaces like this

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new SimpleNamespaceContext(namespaces));
```

This is my expression

```
    String expression = "/ns:Msg/ns:Header/SubsysId";
```

I tried multiple options but not able to get the value.

NOTE: If I remove default namespace and run then I am getting the value.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined `namespaces.put("main", "http:www.defaultnamespace.com");`
then you would need to specify it in your xpath.

So your xpath becomes:

```
String expression = "/ns:Msg/ns:Header/main:SubsysId";
```